# adding a control structure

Tags: java, structure, controls

the code below convert a decimal number to octal number. what i need is to have it to be able to display these message when the input is invalid and repeat the input process until a valid input in entered

"Enter a decimal number: -1

Input should not have any negative sign!

Enter a decimal number: -a

Input should not have any negative sign!

Input should not contain letters!

Enter a decimal number: -1.1

Input should not have any decimal point!

Input should not have any negative sign!

Enter a decimal number: -1.a

Input should not have any decimal point!

Input should not have any negative sign!

Input should not contain letters!

Enter a decimal number: 15 decimal 15 = octal 17"

import java.util.Scanner;

public class apple

{

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );

    System.out.print("Enter a decimal number: ");
    int num =sc.nextInt();


    int rem;
    String str="";

    int num1 = num;
    while(num>0)
    { 
        rem=num%8;
        num=num/8;

        str =rem+str;
    }
    System.out.println("decimal " + num1 + " = octal " + str);
}
```

}

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    boolean continueEntering = true;
    while(continueEntering)
    { 
        int num =sc.nextInt();
        if(your condition failed){
         //print whatever you want
         continueEntering = true; //didnt got the out put so asking again  
        }else{
           //input is valid no need to ask data again
          continueEntering = false; 
        }

    }
```

you need to pass a boolean value at the while loop. If the user has entered a invalid input you can make the boolean value true so that you can ask the input one more time. However i have stopped the program when user has entered a valid input. You can change that by reversing the value of the boolean.